# Should I have a notification screen or just showing a badge the section is enough?

Tags: mobile-application, notification, tab, badge

I'm designing a heavy content app and I first proposed all the notifications to be presented at one notification screen (**option 1**). The screen is a list and each item redirects the user to the proper screen inside other sections.

My doubt is, do this pattern would really help users to find important content or it only overwhelms users with duplicated information? Would it be better to only mark the section with a badge? (**option 2**)

The new information would not necessarily be presented on the main screen of the sections, forcing the user to navigate to find it.

Also, there is **option 3**, but I believe this confuses the user because it he could interpret that there is different information inside each section.

[image: notification options]

Answer (score 2):

I think **Option 2** is the best of the 3 because it allows the user to immediately make a decision about what content they want to see and it does not duplicate notifications, making the screen less mentally busy.

**Option 1** just lets the user know they have notifications, if the user only cares about cart items and the 5 notifications are about Section 2 items, then they will feel like their time has been wasted.

**Option 2** allows the user to choose and only look at new information about cart items and not worry about Section 2 items for the moment, or vice versa.

**Option 3** gives the same decision-making ability to the user as option 2, but it is duplicating information and could be confusing to some users. That said, some users might appreciate a way to see past notifications all in one place, but I would hide it in a submenu or screen so that it doesn't distract non-power users.